# How can I search manpages in 13.10’s dash?

Tags: unity, unity-dash, lenses, 13.10, scopes

In 13.10, there is no dedicated help lens. In 13.04, it was the place for docs like yelp, manpages or texinfo. However, there is a manpage scope in the dash, and it is activated. But when I search for, e.g., "pdftotext", there is no result in the dash.

Is there a way to access manpages, or other help files, through the dash in 13.10?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After having entered the search term in the text field of the Dash we can filter the results to include manpages as a search source:

[image]

This will then display manpages of all installed applications. Selecting the manpage will display its content with Yelp.

Comment: This is called "Smart Scopes" right?

Comment: @Seth: Not sure - I believe "Smart Scope" try to guess what you wanted to then display the right thing. It will fail on me, because I never know for myself what I really wanted ;)

Comment: lol. Can I ask then if you're running Saucy or Raring?

Comment: Interesting. So this is an additional step, but I guess this cycle we are supposed to be trainers to educate the scopes service to be smart enough for 14.04.